# Remove connection is not private

Tags: browser, connection

My browser shows the following "Your Connection is not private" message when i open a website.

[image]

How can I correct this error?

Answer (score 0):

Your browser is telling you, that the name that is embedded into the SSL Server Certificate that was returned by the webserver does not match the name you entered into the address bar.

To solve it, either use the correct DNS name or fetch another certificate with the correct name on it.

Answer (score 0):

The message is usually shown, if the hostname in the URL requested by the browser does not match the one the certificate has been issued for.

Some examples:

- You navigate to `https://localhost/` but the certificate has been issued for `example.com`
- You navigate to `https://example.com` but the certificate has been issued for `example.org`

So ensure, that the CN within the certificate used to secure the connection matches the host name your users will use to access the website.